# Suggest an Optimized code for given Nested Loop

Tags: shell, unix, gnu, gnu-make

Kindly help me to make the below code is more readable or (Suggest Any optimization )

```
    @for i in $(LIST_A); do \
            for j in  $(LIST_B); do\
            if [ "$$i" = "$$j" ] ;then\
             echo " A match found ";\                
            else\
            echo "Not found any corresponding String in LIST_B ";\
                     fi; \
            done\
    done;
```

Comment: Are you just finding intersection between two sets?  There's much better solutions for that:  http://www.catonmat.net/download/setops.txt

Answer (score 0):

not sure what shell language is in your question, but here's a Korn version that you might be able to make use of ...

```
#!/bin/ksh

LIST_A="a b c d e"
LIST_B="d f g"

got_match="0"

for item_A in $LIST_A
do
    #echo $item_A
    for item_B in $LIST_B
    do
        #echo $item_A "  " $item_B
        if [ "$item_A" == "$item_B" ]
        then
            echo "matched " $item_A
            got_match="1"
            break 2;
        fi
    done
done

if [ "$got_match" == "0" ]
then
    echo "no match"
fi
```

The "break 2" gets out of both loops (presuming that's what you want)

"... to make more readable ...", perhaps a style thing, but my suggestions are:

1. use meaningful names rather than i and j
2. avoid multiple statements on one line (avoid using ;)
3. indent properly
4. a comment indicating the intent if it's not obvious

Another suggestion: provide a working version/snippet of code in future questions so others can run to test, and indicate what language it is.